# Why doesn't answering a question automatically upvote the question?

Tags: discussion

Did a quick search and didn't find answer.

I would think that answering a question is an "endorsement" of a question.

Should we also include that reminder in the guidelines?

Comment: this might be a question for meta.stackoverflow.com ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I usually feel that a question that deserves my answer also deserves my upvote, the reverse is sometimes true as well.

E.g. that can be the case when a question is too specific to a single user, and therefore not useful towards building a comprehensive library of questions and answers, but I still want to help the user get an answer.

So, it doesn't automatically upvote, because you're supposed to evaluate whether it deserves an upvote. ;)